# SQL's Confusion on picking ID in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Mysql picking the wrong id when using group by.

If I have a table test with 3 columns id, name, count and has following values.

```
mysql> Select * from test;
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | name  | count |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | david |    10 |
|    2 | david |     5 |
|    3 | david |     3 |
|    4 | david |    40 |
|    5 | navi  |     6 |
|    6 | navi  |     5 |
|    7 | navi  |    29 |
|    8 | navi  |    10 |
+------+-------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here I want to group by the name and in that I want the id of MIN(count). So I tried the below query.

```
mysql> Select id,name,MIN(count) from test GROUP BY name;
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | name  | MIN(count) |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 | david |          3 |
|    5 | navi  |          5 |
+------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The actual result of id for count=3 is 3 and for count=5 is 6, But id shown here is incorrect. So kindly anyone help to achive this use case.

Expected Output :

```
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | name  | MIN(count) |
+------+-------+------------+
|    3 | david |          3 |
|    6 | navi  |          5 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

The above shown already asked question are different with my question

Comment: Your question is equivalent to many others already answered on Stack Overflow. They are usually tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. You are asking for the row with the `MIN()` value, but the technique is the same as those that ask for the row with the `MAX()` value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @BillKarwin, Can you share the exact answer OR other question links ?

Comment: I linked to the _tag_ that has _hundreds_ of answers demonstrating the technique. It's up to you to understand the technique and apply it to your table. Good luck.

Comment: Please note that selecting a non aggregated column in a GROUP BY query is completely undefined/random, unless it is one of the GROUP BY columns. So you are getting exactly the result you asked for. You just didn;t know that ;) ;)

Comment: @Roemer It is defined in the SQL standard (i.e. it should result in an error), but MySQL doesn't (or didn't) bother to implement that behaviour.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: it's a bit more subtle than that.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294989/is-mysql-breaking-the-standard-by-allowing-selecting-columns-that-are-not-part-o   But we're digressing since we were not at all talking about SQL portability. ;)